# Why does the table lines disappear if the cell contains a font-icon

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I would like to have full drawn lines even if the cell contains a font Icon. Why does the line disappear and how can I change this behavior? 
Would be nice if someone could give me a hint in the right direction.

---

**Image:**

[image: Example Image]

---

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>            
               <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Preis</th>
                                <th> </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>john@example.com</td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-secondary"  type="button"> <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Mary</td>
                                <td>Moe</td>
                                <td>mary@example.com</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>July</td>
                                <td>Dooley</td>
                                <td>july@example.com</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try changing it from a **button** tag to a **<a href />** tag. I've done something similar in the past and it worked for me. However, I was using data tables.

Comment: @ZombieChowder Thanks, I tried it but sadly it did not work.

Comment: I can solve your problem using Bootstrap Data Tables. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add the missing `<td></td>` even if they're empty

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>            
               <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Preis</th>
                                <th> </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>john@example.com</td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-secondary"  type="button"> <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Mary</td>
                                <td>Moe</td>
                                 <td> </td>
                                <td>mary@example.com</td>
                                 <td><button class="btn btn-secondary"  type="button"> <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>July</td>
                                <td>Dooley</td>
                                 <td> </td>
                                <td>july@example.com</td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-secondary"  type="button"> <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing/less td tags for 2nd and 3rd body row.

```html
 <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>john@example.com</td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-secondary"  type="button"> <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Mary</td>
                                <td>Moe</td>
                                <td>mary@example.com</td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-secondary"  type="button"> <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>July</td>
                                <td>Dooley</td>
                                <td>july@example.com</td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-secondary"  type="button"> <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```